# End point only ever returns XML

Tags: c#, xml, httpwebrequest

**Question Background:**

I have an API end point that I am calling that is only ever returning XML content.

**The Code:**

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Accept = "application/json";

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())

using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
   ApiResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I have set a header property as shown above that requests a response in JSON but still only XML is ever returned.

Is there a way to have a JSON formatted response returned?

Comment: Does that server supports sending JSON?

Comment: As rene said, it’s all about how the server was done. You can’t just tell a server whatever data type you expect to get if they don’t support it. So he only way to get JSON out is to contact the maker of the end point and ask them to support it. I’m assuming it isn’t you.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Setting `ContentType` doesn't tell the server what to return. It tells the server the format of the content sent in a POST request. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype.aspx.